# how to query against array of integer

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

I would like to query:

#### select * from table where field1 in (1, 2 ,3);

The **field1** is `integer` type.
But for field type is `String` then it would be:

#### select * from table where field1 in ('1', '2' ,'3');

But in Android they both use selectionArs as String[].

```
String[] filter = new String("1", "2", "3");
Cursor altoCursor = mContentResolver.query(
                uri, projection,
                "field1 IN (?,?,?)" +
                filter, null);
```

How is it different than the field type is `String`, say field1 now is type of `String`. The query would look like the same, how does it know if the "1" in the String[] is for a `Integer` or a `String`:

```
String[] filter = new String("1", "2", "3");
Cursor altoCursor = mContentResolver.query(
                uri, projection,
                "field1 IN (?,?,?)" +
                filter, null);
```

Confused here, anyone's help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you have to use `Integer.toString(int)`

Comment: `how does it know if the "1" in the String[] is for a Integer or a String`? By the `field1` data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically The data type of the column that you querying will be defined as an Integer or String.

Database engine will not realize if you are passing string or integer. The moment 
the query is passed to SQL engine it will through error if you are placing integer values in a string column without a quote.

1. Check what column that you are querying
2. If it is string then encode them with a quote
3. if it is integer then you can pass the values as is with as comma separated values

To test if your string is an integer you can use something like 
if (x is an int)

But in this case Android is smart enough to put the code them-self I guess